# How can I run jQuery function only if user hasn’t scrolled?

Tags: jquery, scrolltop, jquery-easing

I’ve been trying to incorporate an auto scroll function on my website ([live here](https://erickdavid.net)). I want it to scroll to the content 6 seconds after load, but only if the user is on the very top of the page and hasn’t scrolled enough to uncover the #introduction element.

I have this code, which works, but I don’t want it to execute if the user has already scrolled by themself:

```
$('html,body').delay(6000).animate({
    scrollTop: $('#introduction').offset().top
}, 1000);
```

I would also like it to happen with a type of ease-in-out, if possible.

Comment: This could be considered bad Interaction Design to force a scroll, why not give the user the choice to scroll if they choose by providing a down arrow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$('html')
  .delay(6000)
  // If the user has scrolled down, do nothing. Otherwise scroll to element
  .queue(function(next) {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
      return;
    } else {
      next();
    }
  })
  .animate(
    {
      scrollTop: $('#introduction').offset().top,
    },
    1000,
    'swing',
  );
```

As for the `ease-in-out` animation you need [JqueryUI](https://jqueryui.com/) for that. `swing` and `linear` are the Jquery library supported easing functions.

Comment: I successfully incorporated the swing easing but when I add the .queue, it breaks the function and makes it do nothing. I don’t understand why.

Comment: @seitsemas my bad I made a small mistake in the if statement. Does it work now?

Comment: It did! Thank you! It’s now fixed.